# Add pandoc command line options to the markdown document itself

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am building a markdown document with options

`-c pandoc-good.css -s --toc -N`

Is it possible to specify these options inside the markdown document instead of the command line?

Especially the css option would be great.

Comment: I'm not aware of an option to do that, but why not put this in a `Makefile` or script in whatever arbitrary language you prefer / makes sense based on your operating system?

Comment: I have multiple markdown files open in VS Code. The settings for pandoc markdown just allow one set of parameters. So when I try to build through VS Code, I often need to edit the settings which is not nice.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be able to use [the `--defaults` option](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--defaults) to achieve what you want:

- Make sure Markdown files that require different settings are in different subdirectories
- Configure your VSCode Pandoc command to be something like

  ```
  pandoc -d defaults.yaml
  ```

  so it will look for a file `defaults.yaml` and use the settings it contains
- Create a `defaults.yaml` file in each directory containing Markdown files and add your settings therein, e.g.

  ```
  css:
  - pandoc-good.css
  standalone: true
  table-of-contents: false
  ```

I'm hoping that VSCode sets the working directory appropriately:

> The [defaults] file will be searched for first in the working directory, and then in the `defaults` subdirectory of the user data directory (see [`--data-dir`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--data-dir)).

Here is [an example defaults file](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--data-dir) showing many more options.